# Input text box focus on blur event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Actually I'm trying to set focus on text-box when focus is lost.The reason behind this is that there is requirement to forcefully set focus on text-box if some validation fails(like empty field validation) and validation is perform on blur event of that text box.
I have tried it on fiddle also but it seems like focus is there but cursor is not blinking.

`Please refer link :`  http://jsfiddle.net/zHeJY/

Please let me know the reason behind this and solution for same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `$("#inputid").focus();`

Comment: @Krish R:I tried with same approach but it also give same result.

Comment: Use the `on()` method. `bind()` was deprecated in v1.7. Or simply just use `blur()`

Comment: @RUJordan : still not working...

Comment: Seems like a bad idea, you're forcing the user to type something that validates, and they can't focus on anything else until they have ?

Comment: @adeneo : Yaa ..but that is the requirement actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First**: This is a bad idea to trap user inside an input unless validation passes! Users should be allowed to focus whatever they want. Ideally, you can prevent a form submission if validation fails.

**Problem**: (1) You don't have any other element in the fiddle you provided. (2) You are not validating anything, just doing an endless loop for blur-focus cycle!

**Solution**:

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zHeJY/7/

With a proper validation routine in place (and another element available), it will work.

*HTML*:

```
<input id="setFocus"/>
<input id="other" />
```

*JS*:

```
$("#setFocus").on("blur", function(e) {
    if (! validate(this)) {
        $(this).focus();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
**HTML**

```
<div id="something">
<input type="text" id="setFocus"/>
<input type="text" id="setFocus1"/>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#something").mouseup("blur",function(){
    $(this).children(":first").focus();
})
```

you should have parent element for this on click of any where you will get the required result

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(document).on('blur', "#setFocus", function (e) {
$(this).focus();
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="setFocus"/>
<input type="text" id="set"/>
</body>
</html>
```